# How to build MinGW W64

Tags: gcc, windows-7, build, g++, mingw

I'm new to Stack Overflow, C++ and to MinGW W64. My problem is, is that I don't know how to build MinGW W64, all I know how to do is double click an exe and install the files onto my computer itself.

So what I am asking is that, how do you build MinGW W64? ( http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ )

If I learn how to build MinGW W64, I think I will be able to build other things without any help. I don't know what files to get to install MinGW W64. All I know  is that I need gcc (for C) and g++ (for C++) from (http://gcc.gnu.org/) .

Yes, I know, I could just install MinGW from http://www.mingw.org/ but their gcc versions are out of date and it would be a nice skill to learn if I learnt how to build these kind of things. (Might even help in the future)

If it helps, my operating system is Windows 7.

Thanks guys. (If possible, can you make a step by step guide on how to build it and tell me what files to get. And if you feel like you want to help a noob out like me, it'd be nice to give the links to the files.)

Comment: Great question, I would like to build my MinGw-w64 as well to fix some GCC issues. FWIW, [MinGW-w64 public mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/mingw-w64-public) might be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 12):

[TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) 4.6.1 (GCC / MinGW / MinGW-w64 compiler suite for 32- and 64-bit Windows) was built on Windows 7 64-bit using MinGW & MSYS. The [source distribution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/Sources/) provide GCC, all support libraries and .sh script files that invoke the Makefile with appropriate arguments.

**BUILD NOTES** ([TDM Sources/README-gcc-tdm-src.txt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/Sources/TDM%20Sources/)) :

```
Building the TDM edition typically looks like this: 
  * [Extract all sources to /crossdev/src] 
  * [Copy or build a previous MinGW installation to a "build root"] 
  * [Ensure the prefix ("/mingw") is empty] 
  * [Ensure the buildroot's "bin" directory is in PATH] 
  * ./build-tdm-[dw2/sjlj].sh support-libs prefix 
  * [Copy everything from the prefix to the "build root"] 
  * [Extract the binutils, mingwrt, and w32api bin/dev packages to the prefix] 
  * ./build-tdm-[dw2/sjlj].sh gcc
```

Answer (score 4):

Today I was also looking for building a native tool-chain, but then ended up using personal build provided there.

For building you can follow this guide -
https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/mingw-w64-doc/howto-build/mingw-w64-howto-build.txt

Comment: Be prepare to write off a day of your life getting that working :)

Comment: If somebody understands the guide mentioned above, please contact me.

Comment: The above link doesn't work any more. The current link is http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/mingw-w64-doc/howto-build/mingw-w64-howto-build.txt